# Can I put 2 command text in MVC Controller?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I'am new in MVC and I encountered this challenge. Where I have 2 queries but it is almost similar. One is for summary and other one is for drilldown.

What I want to achieve is to create two command text in one list controller, and control it by radio buttons.

The idea is something like this:
o Drilldown 
o Summary

when I click the drilldown button, i will call the first query and vice versa with the summary.

My problem is I didn't know what's the right way to control this things.

```
[System.Web.Http.HttpPost]
    public List<ChartData> GetData(STANDCST0058Criteria criteria)
    {
      List<ChartData> result = new List<ChartData>();

      using (var mgr = WebDatabaseHelper.GetHelper())
      {

          PCommand cmd = mgr.GetSQLCommand();
          string draw_myprojects = @"select distinct
                                    p.projectno,
                                    CAST(sum ((cp.samplecost1) / 1000) AS DECIMAL(12,0)) as SC_1, 
                                    CAST(sum ((cp.samplecost2) / 1000)  AS DECIMAL(12,0))  as SC_2
                                    GROUP BY p.projectno";

          string draw_summary = @"SELECT 
                                     CAST(sum ((cp.samplecost1) / 1000) AS DECIMAL(12,0)) as SC_1, 
                                    CAST(sum ((cp.samplecost2) / 1000)  AS DECIMAL(12,0))  as SC_2";

          cmd.AddParameter("@projectId", criteria.Project);
          var dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

          while (dr.Read())
          {
            result.Add(new ChartData()
            {
              ProjectNo          = dr.GetString("ProjectNo"),
              SC_1      = dr.GetDecimal("SC_1"),
              SC_2       = dr.GetDecimal("SC_2"),
            });
          }

          dr.Close();
      }

      return result;
    }
```

Comment: You are referring to asynchronous call, its achievable by jquery.

Comment: Yes sir. but how can I call the commandtext variable using cshtml? quite new to MVC so didn't familiar with the controllers sir.

Comment: You need to handle the `.change()` event of your radio buttons in javascript/jquery and use ajax to update your view, or post a form to a controller method that redirects to a new view